# locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) returning false in API 23

Tags: android, android-studio, gps, location, locationmanager

I want to track GPS status in API 23 mobile, but the above method returing `false` everytime.

My code:

```
  LocationManager locationManager;
            boolean isEnabled;

            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            isEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

**UPDATE :**

I have both the permission in manifest.I have proper code to ask permmision also.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**#** I have observed that if the location is turned on in app opeing the `locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);` is returning true, **but if I'm turning off location when app is opened and again turning on the location it is returning false. It is a big headache to get user current location. Also `fused Location` is freezing.

Comment: Check permission in manifest android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Comment: @Style-7 I have everything ok in manifest & asking permission. But I don't know why locationManager and FusedLocation stops working in some devices. After opeinng the google map app it is working fine.